# JS updating HTML range slider value: I can nudge down in increments of .001 but not up by the same amount?

Tags: javascript, increment, rangeslider

As title, I can nudge down in increments of .001 but not up by the same amount as it seems to jump to the max value?

In the example code, pressing the Nudge - button see's the value decrease by .001 each press, exactly as expected however pressing the Nudge + button I expect an increase of .001 each press but instead it jumps to the max value for the range slider?

```js
updatespeedchange();
function updatespeedchange() {
  document.getElementById('curval').innerText = document.getElementById('p1pitchslider').value;
}

function p1nminus() {
  document.getElementById('p1pitchslider').value = document.getElementById('p1pitchslider').value - .001;
  updatespeedchange();
}

function p1plus() {
  document.getElementById('p1pitchslider').value = document.getElementById('p1pitchslider').value + .001;
  updatespeedchange();
}
```

```css
.contbendnudge {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  width: 45px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 0.5px solid pink;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  grid-template-areas:
    "Nudge Nudge"
    "nminus nplus";
}



.Nudge {
  line-height: 10px;
  grid-area: Nudge;
}

.nminus {
  font-size: 34px;
  line-height: 4px;
  font-weight: 1;

  margin-top: 2px;
  grid-area: nminus;
}

.nplus {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-top: 2px;
  grid-area: nplus;
}
```

```html
<input id="p1pitchslider" oninput="updatespeedchange()" class="pitchslider" type="range" min=".92" max="1.08" value="1" step=.001 autocomplete="off"><span id="curval"></span>
</div><br>

<div class="contbendnudge">
  <div class="Nudge">Nudge</div>
  <div class="nminus" onclick="p1nminus()">-</div>
  <div class="nplus" onclick="p1plus()">+</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that JavaScript is loosely typed, so the plus operator can also cause string concatenation. (Input values are always strings.) If you force the value to a float first it works.

```js
updatespeedchange();

function updatespeedchange() {
  document.getElementById('curval').innerText = 
    document.getElementById('p1pitchslider').value;
}

function p1nminus() {
  document.getElementById('p1pitchslider').value -= .001;

  updatespeedchange();
}

function p1plus() {
  document.getElementById('p1pitchslider').value =
    parseFloat(document.getElementById('p1pitchslider').value) + .001;

  updatespeedchange();
}
```

```css
.contbendnudge {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  width: 45px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 0.5px solid pink;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  grid-template-areas: "Nudge Nudge" "nminus nplus";
}

.Nudge {
  line-height: 10px;
  grid-area: Nudge;
}

.nminus {
  font-size: 34px;
  line-height: 4px;
  font-weight: 1;
  margin-top: 2px;
  grid-area: nminus;
}

.nplus {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-top: 2px;
  grid-area: nplus;
}
```

```html
<input id="p1pitchslider" oninput="updatespeedchange()" class="pitchslider" type="range" min=".92" max="1.08" value="1" step=.001 autocomplete="off"><span id="curval"></span>

<div class="contbendnudge">
  <div class="Nudge">Nudge</div>
  <div class="nminus" onclick="p1nminus()">-</div>
  <div class="nplus" onclick="p1plus()">+</div>
</div>
```